# Kubernetes No external IP

Tags: kubernetes

I installed kubernetes as a single node cluster on a Debian 10 Box.
I changed the dashboard config with :

```
sudo kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit svc kubernetes-dashboard
```

and changed ClusterIP to NodePort and set the port to 32321. As described in this tutorial: https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard/

```
sudo kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.100.91.194   <none>        443:32321/TCP   25m
```

I Still don't get any external IP and can't access the Dashboard via external ip :(

Any advice?

```
sudo kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-9fxkw                     1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-bq79s                     1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/etcd-dyd-001                                 1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/kube-apiserver-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/kube-controller-manager-dyd-001              1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hh5qm                  1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-4pg4r                             1/1     Running   0          136m
kube-system            pod/kube-scheduler-dyd-001                       1/1     Running   0          136m
kubernetes-dashboard   pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-84f48697d6-6sqqt   1/1     Running   0          19m
kubernetes-dashboard   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-689fddb6b4-5sbhf        1/1     Running   0          19m

NAMESPACE              NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  136m
kube-system            service/kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   136m
kubernetes-dashboard   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.98.66.248    <none>        8000/TCP                 19m
kubernetes-dashboard   service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.100.91.194   <none>        443:32321/TCP            19m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     1         1         1       1            1           <none>                   136m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   136m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   136m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   136m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   136m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   136m

NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system            deployment.apps/coredns                     2/2     2            2           136m
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           19m
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           19m

NAMESPACE              NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system            replicaset.apps/coredns-558bd4d5db                     2         2         2       136m
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-84f48697d6   1         1         1       19m
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-689fddb6b4        1         1         1       19m

sudo kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-84f48697d6-6sqqt   1/1     Running   0          17m
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-689fddb6b4-5sbhf        1/1     Running   0          17m

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.98.66.248    <none>        8000/TCP        17m
service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.100.91.194   <none>        443:32321/TCP   17m

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           17m
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           17m

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-84f48697d6   1         1         1       17m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-689fddb6b4        1         1         1       17m

sudo kubectl get svc -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.98.66.248    <none>        8000/TCP        15m
kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.100.91.194   <none>        443:32321/TCP   15m
```

and

```
sudo kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   1/1     1            1           17m
```

and

```
sudo kubectl describe service kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
Name:                     kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:                kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:                   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.91.194
IPs:                      10.100.91.194
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32321/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.6:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: External IP is provided to your cluster (sic!) externally. If it's a cloud environment - you should use your cloud provider guides for that, locally - check the metallb project.

Comment: The VM has already an external IP and I can reach it but I can't connect the External IP to the dashboard

Comment: And that `External IP` is? From what you posted it's `<none>`, right? It really is not clear what actually your final goal is. You can use Node Port, you can forward traffic using iptables DNAT, or use metallb. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Instead of <none> it should show me the external IP of the VM but it doesn't

Comment: It should not, `External IP` is assigned by a load balancer which you don't have.

Comment: @zerkms do you have any documentation on that? How do I create a bad balancer and connect it so that I can access the dashboard and installed pods from my external IP?

Answer (score 1):

You will not see the External  IP for a nodeport service.

Try accessing your dashboard with your server's public IP and port

```
https://<server_IP>:32321
```

Above,  port 32321 is taken  from your output

```
sudo kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.100.91.194   <none>        443:32321/TCP   25m
```

Remember, to use https and that the port will change if you redeploy the service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Kubernetes` service of type `LoadBalancer` like below example that will give you external IP.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Remember for using service of type `LoadBalancer`, you need to use something like `Metallb` or similar for your network.